# Link equivalent to @InjectLink of jersey

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to use the (standard) Link method of building dynamic representations to different resources/methods.
The @InjectLink annotation that's working perfectly fine for me is

```java
public class InjectLinkTest {
    @InjectLink(resource = GraphResource.class, method = "getDataInterval", bindings = { @Binding(name = "dataid", value = "${instance.id}"), @Binding(name = "interval", value = "day") }, condition = "${instance.id != null}")
    public URI day;
    // ...
}
```

This builds the relative link to the resource and method as expected: `/myresource/graphs/3/day` Now I want to do the equivalent of that with the more standard method of using Jax-RS' default `Link`:

```java
public class StandardLinkTest {
    public URI day = Link.fromMethod(GraphResource.class, "getDataInterval").build(this.id, "day").getUri();
    // ...
}
```

I tried this with different options (setting the base URI of the application manually, etc.) but for some reason it never returns the right URI for me. All I get is `3/day` or `http://localhost:8080/3/day` which is not the full (global) path to the resource and method representation but **the path seen from the place the link is built at**, i.e. I'm trying to get the path inside of the entity that `/myresource/graphs` returns. How would I get the equivalent path to the `@InjectLink` annotation with the standard Jax-RS link builder without using hardcoded path parts?
For reference, the correct full path to the target resource would be `http://localhost:8080/myresource/graphs/3/day`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expected behaviour: "Note that the link URI passed to the Link.Builder instance returned by this method is relative." (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Link.html)

One possibility is to use the UriBuilder with / as the basePath.

```
UriBuilder.fromPath("/").path(GraphResource.class, "getDataInterval").build(this.id, "day").getUri();
```

notice: if you are interested in compile-time safe link creation, see here: https://github.com/upsource/jersey-linking/ 
usage (Java-8):

```
@Inject
private Linker linker;
...
linker.link(GraphResource.class, (o) -> o.getDataInterval(this.id, "day"));
```

Comment: Thank you for that great answer! Exactly what I was looking for!